# How can i filter content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really need your help.

I have a div with 7 input elements (buttons) and a clear selection.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">
    <a id="clear-selection" class="clear-selection">Clear Selections</a>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 selectable-buttons-container">
    <input type="button" value="Button 1" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 2"  class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 3"  class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 4"  class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 5" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 6"  class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
    <input type="button" value="Button 7"  class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
</div>
```

Also, i have content with many (over 30 rows) each of them beside other content, has some of the buttons listed in it for example

First row

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 dynamic-divs">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0">
                <input type="button" value="Button 6" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-blue" />
                <input type="button" value="Button 2" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-gray" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <p class="dynamic-div-title">Div Title</p>
                <p class="dynamic-div-text">Div Text</p>
                <p class="dynamic-div-link">See Other Versions <img src="images/arrow-right.png" alt="Arrow"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                 <button class="btn dynamic-div-btn"><img src="images/arrow-right-white.png" class="pull-right" alt="Arrow"> Download</button>
                  <p class="hardened-images">This is some example paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second row

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 dynamic-divs">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0">
                <input type="button" value="Button 3" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-blue" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <p class="dynamic-div-title">Div Title</p>
                <p class="dynamic-div-text">Text</p>
                <input type="button" value="See Other Versions" class="dynamic-div-link"><img src="images/arrow-right.png" alt="Arrow"></input>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5">
                <button class="btn dynamic-div-btn"><img src="images/arrow-right-white.png" class="pull-right" alt="Arrow"> Download</button>
                <p class="hardened-images">This is second example paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, what I need to do is basically a filter, i.e when someone press the Button 1 I will only show all rows that have Button 1 in their content.

Then if someone press Button 3 I will show all the rows that has BUTTON 1 or BUTTON 3 listed inside them etc. until someone press CLEAR SELECTION then its back to default (all rows displayed).

Can someone please help me and tell me a way I can get this done?

I think this can be done with jQuery or pure JS. I have tried to do this and I have some code but to be honest I AM NOT even close to what I need so that's why I thought to ask you hoping someone can help me here.

Comment: You could add classes corresponding to your buttons, like `<input type="button" value="Button 3" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-blue button_3" />` So you could easily filter trough divs that have a input with the class `button_XX`

Comment: @TCHdvlp how can i display the whole row? Can you tell me?

Comment: @DamianDamian you can select only a row that have the corresponding button number or class. `$('.row').has('.button_XX')` for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following code. This will give you what you asked for :)

```js
var hideAllDivs = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  hideAllDivs = true;
});

function showHide(btnClicked) {
  if ($(btnClicked).val() == "Clear All") {
    $("input[type='button']").removeClass('active');
    $("div.row").show();
    hideAllDivs = true;
    return;
  }
  
  if (hideAllDivs) {
    hideAllDivs = false;
    $("div.row").hide();
  }
  
  $(btnClicked).addClass('active');
  $("input[value='" + $(btnClicked).val() + "']").closest('div.row').slideDown();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">
  <a id="clear-selection" class="clear-selection">Clear Selections</a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 selectable-buttons-container">

  <input type="button" value="Button 1" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Button 2" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Button 3" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Button 4" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Button 5" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Button 6" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Button 7" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
  <input type="button" value="Clear All" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" onclick="showHide(this);" />
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 dynamic-divs">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0">
        <input type="button" value="Button 6" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-blue" />
        <input type="button" value="Button 2" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-gray" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <p class="dynamic-div-title">Div Title</p>
        <p class="dynamic-div-text">Div Text</p>
        <p class="dynamic-div-link">See Other Versions <img src="images/arrow-right.png" alt="Arrow"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn dynamic-div-btn"><img src="images/arrow-right-white.png" class="pull-right" alt="Arrow"> Download</button>
        <p class="hardened-images">This is some example paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 dynamic-divs">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0">
        <input type="button" value="Button 3" class="btn btn-sm btn-dynamic-blue" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <p class="dynamic-div-title">Div Title</p>
        <p class="dynamic-div-text">Text</p>
        <input type="button" value="See Other Versions" class="dynamic-div-link"><img src="images/arrow-right.png" alt="Arrow"></input>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5">
        <button class="btn dynamic-div-btn"><img src="images/arrow-right-white.png" class="pull-right" alt="Arrow"> Download</button>
        <p class="hardened-images">This is second example paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This one works as well. But as @KARC answer this one hides the whole webpage content. Can you tell me why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `data-target="..."` to your buttons and when clicked, display these contents that has button target class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var pars = $('#contents p');

    if ($(this).data('target') == 'all') {
      pars.show();
    } else {
      if ($('#contents p:visible').length == pars.length) {
        pars.hide();
      }

      $('#contents p.' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-target="b1">B1</button>
<button data-target="b2">B2</button>
<button data-target="b3">B3</button>
<button data-target="all">Clear</button>
<hr/>

<div id="contents">
  <p class="b1">Content with B1</p>
  <p class="b2">Content with B2</p>
  <p class="b1">Content with B1</p>
  <p class="b3">Content with B3</p>
  <p class="b1">Content with B1</p>
  <p class="b2">Content with B2</p>
  <p class="b1">Content with B1</p>
  <p class="b3">Content with B3</p>
  <p class="b1">Content with B1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be ok for your needs:
https://jsfiddle.net/StarStep/vbc9h4tp/3/

```
function filtercontent(searchfor, where) {
  $(where).each(function() {
    var divtags = '';
    if(typeof searchfor == 'undefined') {
       $(this).slideDown();
       return true;
    }
    $(this).find('.filterinput').each(function() {
      divtags += this.value + ' ';
    });
    if (divtags.indexOf(searchfor) < 0) {
      $(this).slideUp();
    } else {
      $(this).slideDown();
    }
  });
}
$('.filterme').click(function() {
  filtercontent(this.value, '.row');
});
```

Comment: this kinda works. But when i press on the buttons the whole content disappears (header, footer, content... everything). Can you tell me why is that?

Comment: Ok, i found out this was my mistake. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: i just saw that its only showing results for one item. How can change it so it will work for every click until clear selection is clicked. For example if someone click on button 1 it shows content only for button 1. But if he then click on button 2 BEFORE he clicks on clear selection it will show results for both button 1 and button 2.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery necessarily. It can be solved in pure JS.

```
<script>
        var selectBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-selectable-blue');
        var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
        for (var i = 0; i < selectBtns.length; i++) {
            selectBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                var patternToFind = this.value;
                for (var j = 1; j < rows.length; j++) {
                    var currentStr = rows[j].innerHTML;
                    var containsDesired =currentStr.indexOf(patternToFind);
                    if (containsDesired != -1) {
                        rows[j].innerHTML = "";
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

at first some advice:
you will need to add some specific classes or name attribute to your html row so set your architecture more understandable and easier to manipulate

ex

....

Avoid to set input value with space :
ex

```
    <input type="button" value="button_1" class="btn btn-sm btn-selectable-blue" />
```

If you need to post these informations add name attribute and id to your input

Practise:
Considering that jquery lib is loaded, and callable with $.
All your rows must have an attribute style like "display:none;", 
then on the button input add :
    onclick="$('.' + this.value).show()"
this will dynamicaly display all rows there have input value as class.
it's a way of beginning what you want to do.